# how do you return nil if a certain type is passed to a function in Swift?

Tags: ios, random, swift, switch-statement, return-type

ok so I am trying to return nil if a certain type is passed into my function. In this case im passing in an instance of my class "BlogPost" and a type within this blogpost. I also have an array called "types" and I have assigned the variable Videos to the last index of that array. If this type is passed into my function I would like to return nil (so assuming im going to need an optional here for returning a possible nil) this is what I have so far :-

[image]

so all in all I need to pass in an instance of my blog post but always return nil if a certain type is passed in. Hope this makes sense

---

Update:

The `types` array is defined as follows:

```
let types : [String] = ["technology", "Fashion", "Animals"]
```

this is the array I am referring to in the function. Basically if that last entry of the array is entered into the function I need to return nil

sure this is blogpost it does actually have an empty string for type

[image]

great so im getting there what Ive done now is change the blogpost.type to choose one at random. So now if the specfic type is chosen from this array how would I do that still getting an error. This is what I have updated to

[image]

so now all I need to do is access the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLhCF.jpg) type in that array and if I do access it return nil. Any thoughts on that?   so to drag it on   thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the definition of the `Type` property? Likewise, can you show us the definition of this `types` array? Generally you'd use an `enum` type in these sorts of cases. Or are you dynamically building the array of `types`?

Comment: just added it now. The type property within BlogPost is just an Empty string

Comment: OK. And can you show us how `Type` of `BlogPost` is defined? Regardless, if it's `nil` or empty string, then you either (a) need to change your code that set this value to make sure it set it to one of your three available values in your `types` array; and/or (b) write your `randomViews` code to handle it if the `BlogPost.Type` is not one of the values you expected.

Comment: Check the type of the blog. using  `BlogPost.isKindOfClass(NSString)`

Comment: @RichyGarrincha The `BlogPost.Type` does not mean what I think you think it means. If your `blog` parameter is intended to be a `String` value that you will compare to your `types` array values, then define the `blog` parameter to be `String`, not `BlogPost.Type`. Also, if you define this parameter to be optional (e.g. `String?`), then make sure you test and handle `nil` values appropriately.

Comment: ah your right, so would I just enter BlogPost? then access the type property via blog.type    ?

Comment: A couple of suggestions: First, don't post your code snippets as images. Paste it in as code (indented by four spaces on each line). Second, your final edit appears to be different question (and, worse, you say you're getting error but don't tell us what that error is). One of the purposes of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of questions and answers that will be useful for future readers, and when you shift the question like this, it largely diminishes its value for posterity. I'd would suggest editing out that last update, accept an answer, and then post a new question.

Comment: ok thanks I am new here and still getting to grips with posting question will post as a new question which is more clear to what I need thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `blog` as a `BlogPost.Type` parameter. That is not correct. You should have either just passed it the `String` parameter, or you could pass it the `BlogPost` itself:

```
func randomViews(blog: BlogPost) {
    let videos = types[2]

    if blog.type == videos {
        // do whatever you want
    }

    // carry on
}
```

Unrelated to your question at hand, but notice that I use `let` instead of `var` when defining `videos`. Always use `let` if the value will not (and cannot) change.

Also note that I use lowercase letter `v` in `videos`, because Cocoa naming conventions dictate that variables generally start with lowercase letters, whereas types, classes, structs, and enums generally start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. You can create failable initialisers which does what you need but you cannot use it with normal function.

The best solution for you would be return optional Int or String and when you call the function just check the result for nil and do what you need to do, otherwise ignore it:

```
func randomViews(blog : BlogPost.Type) -> Int? {
    case 10:
    return nil
    case 10, 20 :
    return 0
    default:
    random

}

if (randomViews(parameter) == nil) {
    //function returned nil
}
```

You have displayed error because you compare optional blog to Videos, you have to unwrap it first, for example if you are sure the blog has always have a value use:

```
if blog! == Videos
```

if not sure is safer to use:

```
if let blg = blog {
    if blg == Videos {
}
else {
    // blog has not have a value
}
```